# TreeView Index - ScrollIntoView?

Tags: wpf, treeview, indexing, focus, scrollviewer

I've got a TreeView in a WPF Application which has an Index that is changed outside of the TreeView itself.

How can I use a ScrollIntoView (such a function like for DataGrid) option for such a TreeView when it is out of Focus?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try using the Expanded event of the TreeView like this:

```
private static void TreeView1_Expanded(object sender, RouterEventArgs e)
{
    var tvItem = (TreeViewItem)e.OriginalSource;
    var itemCount = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(tvItem)

    for (var i = itemCount-1; i>=0; i--)
    {
        var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(tvItem, i);
        ((FrameworkElement)child).BringIntoView();
    }
 }
```